# When to use a genitive pronoun instead of a possessive adjective

Tags: grammar-choice, pronouns, genitive

The genitive form of the personal pronouns (e.g. *mei*, *tui*, *nostri*, *nostrum*, etc.) seem to occur fairly often in the following contexts:

1. **Partitive genitive**: to indicate a part of some whole.

> *Quis vestrum non morietur?*

2. **Objective genitive**

> *Metus tui*

3. **With an adjective that takes the genitive**

> *Memor mei esto!*

4. **With a verb that takes the genitive**

> *Miserere nostri!*

My question: **is there any classical precedent for using the possessive personal pronoun to indicate possession?** In other words, are there any examples of *mei* being used instead of *meus* in a sentence like the following: *Filius es mei?* In English we can say things such as "He is a son of mine," and other languages have parallels, e.g. *mon fils à moi* or *un hijo mío*.

If there is, **what nuance of meaning is this used to convey?**

Comment: I just realized after posting that the "son of mine" phrases would probably be best translated with dative *mihi*, but I think it is still a useful example.

Comment: Interesting question. I have never seen such use and I guess the answer is "no", but, as always, proving non-existence is difficult. Would it be a sufficient answer to quote a comprehensive grammar that does not mention that possibility?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, that might work, though it would be nice if there is a grammar that distinctly rejects the construction. I just found [this resource](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Latin/Lesson_6-Pronouns) that rejects it explicitly, albeit perfunctorily.

Comment: I share Joonas's expectation. Another situation where I would expect a genitive, though, is as a genitivus objectivus: *metus tui* "fear of you".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, thoughts on [this quote from Priscian](https://books.google.com/books?id=jm9oAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA213&q=%22mei%20nata%2C%20Lavinia%20est%22)?

Comment: @brianpck, perplexing. I would read *mei nata* as "the daughter of my son/brother/father/other male related to me". It seems to me that the verse in the quote speaks about a daughter of some man who is related to the one who speaks. I would need more context (and time) to form a more solid opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging, it appears that **this construction is rare but is attested in several classical authors.**

Pinkster's *Oxford Latin Syntax* (p. 977ff) is my guide. He states:

> The use of the genitives of the personal pronouns *nostrum* and *vostrum* instead of the corresponding possessive adjectives is rare.

Two examples from Cicero:

> Recordamini qui dies nudius tertius decimus fuerit, quantus **consensus vestrum**, quanta virtus, quanta constantia. (Cic. *Phil.* 5.2)

This example "sounds" like a partitive genitive, but I still think the use of the genitive pronoun instead of the possessive adjective is remarkable.

> Is enim **splendor** est **vestrum** ut eadem postulentur a vobis quae ab amplissimis civibus. (Cic. *Att.* 7.13.3)

This is an unmistakable example.

Above all, this construction seems to occur with the reflexive possessive pronoun, *sui*. Here are some examples:

> Lysander Lacedaemonius magnam reliquit **sui famam**, magis felicitate quam virtute partam. (Nep. *Lys.* 1.1)

and:

> Non aliud Scaevolae Mucio cognomen dedit et capto contra Porsennam regem libertatem relquit quam **vilitas sui**. (Sen. *Con.* 8.4.1)

Pinkster provides more examples in *op. cit.* p. 978.

As for *mei* and *tui*, the only example of this usage is in the dubious context of a paraphrase by Priscian (who is decidedly post-classical). Glossing the Virgilian verse "Est mihi nata, viro gentis quam iungere nostrae...", he says:

> nam ad scientes, esse natam, nomen autem proprium ignorantes, dixisset 'mea' vel '**mei nata**, Lavinia est', subdistinctione posita post 'natam'.... (Pris. *Inst* XVIII)

As for nuances of meaning, the construction seems so rare that it is hard to speculate: in some of the above examples, hints of a partitive ("consensus vestrum") and objective ("famam sui") meaning appear. In others, the reason is less obvious.