# How do I thank someone for helping me in Latin?

Tags: sentence-translation

I am trying to thank someone for their help in Latin. Here are two sample sentences I tried to translate, with my attempt *in italics.*

> Thank you for your help. - *Gratias propter auxilium tui tibi ago.*
>
> Thank you for helping me. - *Gratias propter adiuvandum mihi tibi ago.*

1. Is ***propter*** a good word here? What could be better words?
2. Is ***adiuvandum*** the right way to translate ***helping***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first attempt, the only issue is that *tuus, -a, -um* should agree with *auxilium*. The genitive pronoun *tui* is not usually used for possession, [with some rare counterexamples](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective). I would thus amend to:

> Gratias propter auxilium tuum tibi ago.

As for your second sentence, I would advise against using the gerund in this way. The accusative of a gerund is almost always used with *ad* to express purpose, and it would be incorrect to use it alone in this way.

As a more general comment, the "two" sentences you are translating are semantically identical. It's an easy trap to fall into, thinking that *help* or *helping* need to be translated respectively by a noun or gerund. Especially with Latin translation, you need to focus on the *sense* of the sentence much more than the individual words.

As for your first question, *propter* is perfectly fine, though I tend to prefer *ob* as a shorter (and [fairly well-attested](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23gratias+~+%23ob%23)) combination. One possibility:

> **Gratias ob auxilium tibi ago.**

If you wish to emphasize the fact that the person was helping *me*, a more prolix version could be:

> **Ob auxilium mihi oblatum gratias tibi [plurimas] ago.**

Which is literally:

> Thank you [very much] for the help you have given me.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, in last translation: does ***oblatum*** carry meaning that it was *you* who gave help or sentence is something more like *Thank you [very much] for the help that was given to me*?

Comment: Is _gratias dare_ (as opposed to _agere_) classical too?

Comment: @PrzemysławP It literally means "the help offered to me" (offero > oblatus). It's impossible to construe this without "you" because of the later "tibi."

Comment: @Rafae; I've never heard *gratias dare*: pretty sure that would just be an English/Spanish calque!

Comment: @brianpck *It's impossible to construe this without "you" because of the later "tibi."* You could theoretically thank someone for help that was given to you by someone else ;)