# When should you use genitive pronouns and when should you use possessive adjectives?

Tags: grammar-choice

I was reading @brianpck's post about [genitive pronouns vs possessive adjectives](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective), and trying to understand when it's better to use one versus the other.
Compare these two sentences:

> Mater non est apud filios, ea in peristylo est; illic virum suum exspectat.

And

> Puella lacrimat: in oculis eius sunt lacrimae.

Is there a reason to use one vs the other? Is it based purely on whether the person possesses the object, or is it more of a stylistic choice?

Comment: Just to clarify: your example focuses on the difference between a reflexive possessive adjective (*suus*) and a non-reflexive personal pronoun (*eius*). My linked question was asking about situations where the reflexive vs. non-reflexive distinction didn't come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice is not merely stylistic.
The general rule is that *suus* refers to the subject of the clause, *eius* to someone else.
There is some variation between the two, but the general rule of thumb is that there is a difference.

Your first example can be simplified to: *Mater maritum suum/eius expectat.*
With *suus* the mother is waiting for her own husband.
With *eius* she is waiting for someone else's husband.
In isolation it feels weird, but with some context we can make the contrast:

> *Mater cum amico in horto sedens maritum suum/eius expectat.*
> Sitting in the garden with her friend, the mother waits for her/his husband.

I chose the friend to be male so that I can make the English contrast in one word.
If you use *amica* instead, it would be "her own husband"/"her friend's husband".

In a subordinate clause *suus* can also refer to the subject of the governing clause, so there can be ambiguity.
For example:

> *Marcus dixit Gaium se amare.*
> Marcus said that Gaius loves him/himself.

With "him" *se* refers to the subject *Marcus* of the governing clause, with *himself* it refers to the subject *Gaius* of the subordinate ACI structure.
Both are valid readings.

In your second example *eius* looks like the only plausible choice, unless you argue that there is effectively subordination that makes reference to the girl possible.
You can say *Caesar in castris suis manet* when Caesar stays in his camp, but what does it mean if tears are in their own eyes?
As tears have no eyes, one would interpret *in oculis suis* as *in oculis eius*.

Comment: So to use my original two quotes, the first is _mother waits for her husband_ (_her_ being a possessive adjective since she is the subject), and the second is _the girl cries: in the girl's eyes are tears_ (genitive pronoun). I'm being very literal for my own sake so I can clearly see the distinction.

Comment: @Adam Exactly! If you want extra emphasis for the first one, you can use "her own husband".

Comment: Great! Future me thanks you when I come back to refer to this post again at some point.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: In the original Q., both yourself and brianpck questioned the use of "mei nata" (Priscian). Brian also questioned (in his answer) Cicero's use of genitive pronouns (the first two examples) when possessive adjectives were expected. There is a natural tendency to accept anything Cicero says as Gospel (truth), which stifles debate. Four-years on it will be interesting to see if there is any fresh thinking on these points, from anyone.

Comment: @tony At least I don't have any new thoughts on that.