# Seeking feedback on English to Latin song translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, poetry, ecclesiastical-latin, song-lyrics

I am working on a translation of a song from English into Latin at a friend’s request. The song will be used in a Catholic Church context (prayer/worship). For that reason, I have tried to draw vocabulary from the Vulgate and traditional Catholic sources where possible (e.g. “liquefacere” from the prayer of St. Bonaventure in the Roman Missal for “explode”). I have tried to preserve the meter in the original and rhymed the first two lines of each verse.

> English:
> In disguise I come, I humble Myself
> Can you see Me, I am here
> Your deepest need,
> Your deepest desire is for Love
> Love is here
> I am here
> Take
>
> Verse 2
> Love for you consumes Me
> My Heart explodes
> Covering you with water, with blood
> I claim you as Mine
> Consume Me
> Let My Love consume you
> Eat

> V.1
> Absconditus veniam, me humilio
> Vosne me videtis? ego maneo
> Desiderium profundum
> caritatis est
> Hic est caritas
> Adsum
> Accipite
>
> V.2
> Consumptus, effusus, pro vobis ego sum
> Liquefacit amore vestri cor meum
> Aquam sanguinemque mei vobis effundo
> Mei nominati
> Consumite me
> Ut vos consumat amor meus
> Manducate

I would welcome any suggestions. In particular,

1. Can anyone suggest a better phrase than “desiderium profundum caritatis est” in v.1 to convey the idea that “your deepest desire is for love”?
2. “Mei nominati” in v.2 is intended as a vocative phrase addressing “you who are called ‘mine’”. Is this sufficiently clear?

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you, Adam!

Comment: Welcome. Several points to consider (for now I prefer them in a comment). I'm not sure about the meter restrictions. **(1)** about *pro vos*. pro comes with the ablative, so maybe *pro vobis*. But you can consider using *propter vos*. **(2)** about *Aquae sanguinisque mei vobis effundo* not sure I understand the grammar here, can you comment about the usage of the genitive? **(3)** about *maneo* : consider adsum (as used afterwards), or *pareo* to keep the meter. **(4)** about *Mei nominati*, I wonder if just *mei* (as pl. or *meus*) might do for you. or *mei nomine*  (Jos. 5:13 noster es an..

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to view your entire comment? It’s cut off for me in the middle of the citation you gave from Jos. 5:13. I’ve corrected “pro vos” to “pro vobis” and “aquae sanguinisque” to “aquam sanguinemque” (for some reason I was under the impression that effundo would take the genitive, but the examples in L&S show otherwise). I rather like “maneo” for the resonance with Jn 1:39 (‘viderunt ubi maneret, et apud eum manserunt’).

Comment: How about something like “vos vocati mei” instead of “mei nominati”?

Comment: @MatthewKnight, My comment wasn't cut. My bad. I should have finish it with "etc."  instead "...". **N**ow *maneo* usually means "I stay/remain" so it seems quite off (to me) from the English "I'm here". but if *maneo* works good for you, use it. **A**bout *mei nominati* I was unsure about this one. I don't know if that conveys the required meaning of "you are call by my name". Hence I suggested simply *mei* (as Jos 5:13 suggests it makes sense with the *noster es* could be *meus es*); or suggested *mei nomine* ("mine, by name). A more explicit could be *Meo nomine vocati* (but again unsure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how much you want changed, so I'll just tackle your two questions for now.

1. What about: *Super omnia amorem desideras*, "You desire love above all." (cf. Aeneid 9.283)
2. Is there a reason you're in the plural here? But anyway, the grammar breaks down heavily here. Why is it vocative? The lack of punctuation in the English is actually an impediment to translation. If there is supposed to be a period (or semicolon) after *effundo*, I would make the pronoun explicit, especially since there is ambiguity in the grammar.

One way of solving all the ambiguity is to make a relative clause with a dative of possession:

> Qui mihi sunt
> Me consumite

> You who belong to me,
> Devour me

You could even add an *in nomine* ("in name") after the *mihi* if you want to express the idea that it's just a label, a supposition, not necessarily fact (but not necessarily false, either).

One problem with *consumere* is that it also means "kill, lay waste to." Make sure you're ok with that definition too, otherwise you might want to try words like *vorare* (for which that destructive element is more closely tied to eating).

Other minor points: you don't need the *ego* in *ego sum* and *ego maneo*. Without punctuation *consumite me ut me consumat amor meus* means "Devour me so in order that my love devours you." Is that what you were intending?

This is all *highly erotic*, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for that last line!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer, @cmw. The suggestion from the Aeneid was most helpful. Regarding your last aside—although I am only a translator (an amateur at that) and don't presume to know the author's mind—I would point out there is a long tradition of Christian and indeed Jewish spirituality that might be called 'erotic'. See the Song of Songs and the writings of the mystics (Teresa of Avila springs especially to mind). Pope Benedict also wrote a [document](https://www.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xvi_enc_20051225_deus-caritas-est.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @d_e, @cmw and @brianpck for your corrections and suggestions. Regarding (1), we went with "super omnia amorem desideratis." Regarding (2), the author decided to take out the line in question, which saved a great deal of trouble. Your points about possible unwanted connotations of "maneo" and "consumo" were well made and appreciated, but we decided to keep both of them, in part due to their resonances with Jerome's Vulgate (see e.g. 'maneo' in Jn. 1:39 and 'consumo' in Lev 6:23) as well as elsewhere in Catholic tradition.

Below is the final version of the Latin lyrics.

> Verse 1
>
> Absconditus veniam, me humilio
> Vosne me videtis? ego maneo
> Super omnia amorem desideratis
> Hic est caritas
> Adsum
> Accipite
>
> Verse 2
>
> Consumptus, effusus, pro vobis ego sum
> Liquefit amore vestri cor meum
> Aquam sanguinemque meum vobis effundo
> Consumite me
> Ut consumamini
> Manducate

Comment: A few more comments: (1) *liquefacio* literally means to "melt," but it is transitive, i.e. I can use it to say that I *melt* gold but not that gold *melts.* In this case, you want to use the passive (*liquefit*, *liquefactum est*) or a different word (*liquescit*; cf. Ps. 21). (2) The genitive pronoun *mei* is [almost never used](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective) for possession: you should probably rephrase to *sanguinem meum* or (better, in my opinion) drop the *mei*.

Comment: These are very helpful. Thanks, @brianpck.