# Why do we write “cum marito eius” (cum + abl+ gen.) and not “cum marito ei” (cum + abl+ abl.)?

Tags: ablative, genitive, cum

Pline wrote this sentence:
“*Sunt mihi et cum marito eius Minicio Iusto, optimo viro, vetera iura; fuerunt et cum filio maxima, adeo quidem ut praetore 5 me ludis meis praesederit*”.
I don’t understand why we have “cum marito eius” (cum + abl+ gen.) and not “cum marito ei” (cum + abl+ abl.).
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two issues that would be helpful to clarify here:

1. ***ei* is the dative (not the ablative) of the demonstrative pronoun *is/ea/id***. Since Latin does not have a third-person personal pronoun, this [demonstrative pronoun](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/demonstrative-pronouns-paradigms) is used to mean *he/she/it*.
2. **The [possessive adjective](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/possessive-pronouns-paradigm) *suus, -a, -um* is only used reflexively.** (See the first note under §145 of the linked grammar entry from Allen & Greenough.)

Thus, if you want to say his/her/its, there are two options in Latin:

- Use the adjective *suus, -a, -um* agreeing with the noun, if it refers back to the subject, e.g. *pater amat filium suum* = "the father loves his [own] son."
- Use the genitive pronoun *eius*, as a standalone, if it does *not* refer back to the subject, e.g. *pater amat filium eius* = "the father loves his [someone else's] son."

In short: **there is no non-reflexive third-person possessive adjective.**

In the third-person, this is a relatively fixed rule. You'll note that there are cases, like the first-person adjective *meus, -a, -um* and genitive pronoun *mei*, where there isn't the same reflexive vs. non-reflexive distinction. In such cases--as your instincts tell you here--Latin [almost always](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/when-to-use-a-genitive-pronoun-instead-of-a-possessive-adjective?noredirect=1&lq=1) prefers the adjective, not the genitive pronoun.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear and structured answer.